# Is there a term for the group of individual organisms whose matrilineally descended female ancestors all share a common ancestor?

Tags: terminology

A group of individual organisms that are all descended from a common ancestor is a clade. Is there a term for a group of individuals whose matrilineally descended ancestors (mothers, maternal grandmothers, maternal grandmothers' mothers, etc.) are all descended from a common ancestor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any one-word term for this. The term "common mitochondrial ancestor" is often used to refer to a shared female ancestor of a genetically related group. If you want to specify female descendants only, perhaps you could say "females sharing a common mitochondrial ancestor". I think that's about the shortest way to say it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not specifying only females at the end of the chains, but every link above every group member must be female until you get to a female who is a common ancestor. So "all individuals who share a mitochrondrial ancestor" does the job nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a word for that.

However, you can refer to this specific DNA sequence as being exclusively maternally inherited (such as [mtDNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_DNA) for example; see also [mtEve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_Eve)). For this sequence, the classical vocabulary from the field of phylogenetics and population genetics apply nicely.